# Pages displaying differently in preview and live

Tags: publishing, 2013-sp1, content-manager

We are working on the migration project there were vbscript templates coverted to c# templates etc .
We have two target types preview and Live .

We published the same page for both target types but still in preview site the page has alignment issue where as in live site the page is coming up fine without any issues.

We faced one more issue for other page in preview image was not coming on the page in live it was coming. When we check in tridion shows that image is published to both target but when check in DB that item was not present in the published state to preview target

I know the resolution for this type of issues on re-publishing it works but want to know the What is the root cause for such type of issues.

If anyone faced this type of issues please let me know the root cause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a general rule, the published content cannot be different on different targets unless you are handling them differently in templating code.

For alignment issue, I’d suggest you to compare published content for Preview and Live. And if the content is different, please check the latest published content is ending up in File system/ Broker (depending on your configuration). If the content is same, please check the CSS is same at both targets.

About the image issue, as you mentioned the images were not ending up in broker DB for preview target; so this could be a configuration issue (storage config) for the preview target. With republishing the images starts coming means someone has corrected the configuration so that the images are now ending up in broker database.

So to answer your question, it could be a CD storage configuration issue for preview target.

Comment: Content and CSS are same for both the targets but alignment issue exist for preview and in our case overall alignment, link, image and tab issue exist only in preview in live everything is coming up fine. We don't have any content, CSS and Js differences across the site and we are handling same templates. this image issue exist in only some of the pages but in rest of the pages for preview image is coming up fine checked the storage config didn't find any issue

Comment: If published content, CSS and JS are same then it's not a tridion issue, it's a environment related issue. 
For Images, If republishing fixes the issue; it means there were some issues when the pages previously published.

Comment: can you please give me more info about environment related issues

Answer (score 1):

Will share my experience. Usually on the Preview/Staging servers, the Websites were hosted in sub folders. for example:

```
http://preview*****.test.com/nl_nl for our netherlands website.
```

The issues we faced on our Preview website were the same as of yours:

- Images NOT displaying
- Layout/Appereance/alignments issue
- Links not working / 404 on clicking links
- Javascript functions not working

Below are our observations on Environment setup and the resolutions:

1. The `Publication Url` was set to / in Publications property, thus it didn't accounted for the subfolder `nl_nl`

Seeing the websites were hosted as subfolders on `Preview` but as a separate Website in IIS on Live servers, it didn't make any sense to change the Properties: `Publication Path/Url` and `Images Path/URL` of the Publication.

2. [ CSS/JS Path Issue ]: `cd_storage_conf.xml` has below setting present for the nl website:

`<Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory"

   Id="filesystemStoragePublicationId121">
    <Root Path="E:\Preview-stage\preview****.test.com" />
  </Storage>`

You see the `Path` value is incorrect. The subfolder `nl_nl` is missing. This was forcing the Published Content to go to wrong directory.

Correct Setting is:

```
<Root Path="E:\Preview-stage\preview****.test.com\nl_nl" />
```

Also, The Template code( PT DWTs) had references to many CSS / JS  through that usual `<link rel="" />` and `<script .../>` way. We corrected the template code, so that when a Page  is published to Preview server, the path to such resources (CSS/JS) are corrected.

3. [Link Issue]: The dynamic link resolver config file: `cd_link_conf.xml` was missing an Entry for this Publication. 
   The below entry was missing/incorrect for few websites earlier.  This entry also decides how URLs to images and other resources are constructed.

   `<Publication Id="121">
     <Host Domain="preview......solutions.com/nl_nl" Port="80" Path="/" />
     <Linking ComponentAnchors="false" AddComponentLinkInfo="false" />
   </Publication>`

Comment: In our case everything goes to the DB if anything wrong in the configuration event the content should not come on the page, some images are coming and some are not even same case with alignment for some of the pages not having any issue and in some pages issues are present related to image, link , alignment.

Comment: thanks R.C and Saurabh :- Alignment issue got resolved when compared the page source of both preview and live pages some of the CSS were not rendered for the preview and may be not included then investigating more by including those missed CSS to the preview

Comment: By adding missing CSS preview page comes up fine without any issues

Comment: @k951 : When you say Missing CSS : Do you mean they were missing on presentation server ? or the Path to such CSS was incorrect ?

Comment: After investigating more found that there are some scripts like 
<link media="all" href="/system/css/reset.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">  
<link media="all" href="/system/css/rcpromo.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">  
<link media="all" href="/system/css/components_home.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">  
included in component . this script component is included in the main component. component is published to both targets and verified in the CD DB there also item  exist but for preview these scripts are not coming on the page .

Comment: component is showing published to preview but in CD db item is not present sry for wrong info before. still analyzing to find the RCA